# Build time for aws-sdk-ios on CI with Carthage

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, aws-sdk, carthage

I am using Carthage and aws-sdk-ios. I use just 2 projects from `aws`, but Carthage needs to build all the other 20+ libraries.

On BuddyBuild this means 40 minutes to build. It's impossible to work like this in a team.

This is in the Cartfile:
`github "aws/aws-sdk-ios"`

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Tools like [Rome](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi95eOg5fvUAhWHKGMKHShIDUUQFggyMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fblender%2FRome&usg=AFQjCNHWAPuW6a1OdkyI8_26p0orxg7tqw) are super useful to speed up CI builds by storing the results in S3.